# how to force TextBox to only accept strings

Tags: asp.net, string, textbox

Sorry for the Dummy Question , i know :( ,, but it's only the simple things that dont work with me :((

i have many text boxes and i want the user to only insert String and not Numeric numbers ,
how could i handle it in easy way ??
as it takes every thing and apply it to the database  , or should i control it from the Database 
PS. i have searched a lot but with no good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [a-zA-Z]+ for ValidationExpression:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
    ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: how about including spaces and dots?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at validation techniques for asp : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542.aspx

This provide a set of tools to check whether the input match what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily in AJAX,just download it from [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

first add a script manager to your page then add `FilteredTextBoxExtender` to the textbox and set it's properties as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

A Regular Expression could be applied to the input

For the basics on RegEx : http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

And also see 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do that with `jQuery`.

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gLBRV/), I replace only digits.

You can adapt the regex to replace any set of characters with an empty string.

Comment: You wouldn't want to rely on javascript to filter input though, it would be better to also check on the server as well as the client side.